# Navigation, AMCL, amcl_pose

Tags: navigation, amcl-pose, fake-localization, amcl, dwa-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm debugging the navigation stack set up on my robot. My question is about `amcl_pose`. This topic is published by `amcl` (or `fake_localization`), and in my robot `amcl_pose` is being published to by the localization module too, but no topic is subscribed to `amcl_pose`.

As I understand, local planner should use `amcl_pose` and I'm using [DWAPlannerROS](http://wiki.ros.org/dwa_local_planner#DWAPlannerROS) in the navigation stack, and `DWAPlannerROS` is only subscribed to `odom`.

So, the question is which component is using the result of the localization module.

**UPDATE 1:** Another suspicious thing with `amcl` (or `fake_localization`) is, although it is publishing to `/particlecloud`, but I can not visualize the particles in `Rviz` using `/particlecloud` topic. Nothing appears in `Rviz`.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192922/navigation,-amcl,-amcl_pose/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-09-18

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2014-09-18**:
Regarding the /particlecloud visualization in Rviz: I vaguely recall having trouble seeing this topic and I *think* it was because I had the wrong FixedFrame selected in Rviz. You *can* see the /particlecloud topic in Rviz if you have the right settings.

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-09-19**:
My FixedFrame is map. and everything works and looks fine in rviz, except particlecloud

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2014-09-26**:
Please forgive if this is a dumb question, but have you given the robot an `initialpose`? Another: does your particlecloud topic show up in the 'By Topic ' tab of the Add dialog in Rviz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the wiki on DWAPlannerROS,

> odom - Odometry information that gives the local planner the current speed of the robot

So the planner uses odom only for the instantaneous velocities. While it could extract the robot_pose from amcl_pose, it actually does this using the tf library (/tf topic) instead.

In more detail, the plugin doesn't actually obtain the pose itself, but actually gets the pose from move_base's [costmap](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/hydro-devel/dwa_local_planner/src/dwa_planner_ros.cpp#L254).

---

Also going by the wiki, [amcl](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) publishes `/particlecloud` as a `PoseArray`, which would be why you can't visualize it directly in rviz. You should be able to tap into the topic using `rostopic echo` though.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-09-18**:
Thanks Paul, So it is normal that no topic is subscribed to `/amcl_pose`?

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-09-18**:
Yes      .

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-09-19**:
regarding `/particlecloud`, according to [this video](http://youtu.be/0CsSok3QgZk?t=55s), the topic should be visualizable in rviz

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-17**:
As an update, `PoseArray`s can be [visualized now](https://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/PoseArray).